# Remove fragments that are not put on backstack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

My simple **layout** only has a fragment placeholder:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

I firstly add a **1st fragment** to this placeholder:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, firstFragment, "first"); //I did not put to backstack
```

I have a **2nd fragment**, which replace the above fragment and **put it to back stack**:

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

//initialize an fragment instance
Fragment secondFragment = initSecondFragment(); 

//replace with the fragment 
fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, secondFragment, "second");

//Add fragment transaction to back stack
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);

//commit the transaction
fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragTrans.commit();
```

Later I have some fragments replace the previous fragment, but **NOT put on backstack**.

It seems for those fragment which **have not been put on backstack** will always showing on screen, the back button press will have not effect to them.

So, **How to find those fragments which are not on backstack** in my app, and **how to remove them from screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find those fragments which are not on backstack in my app

Call `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` on your `FragmentManager`.

> how to remove them from screen?

Use `remove()` with a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: How to check whether a fragment is added to Backstack or not ??

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585: This really belongs as a separate StackOverflow question. That being said, if you are passing a tag to `addToBackStack()`, you can iterate over the back stack entries via methods like `getBackStackEntry()` on `FragmentManager`, to find the entry with the desired tag. Fragments themselves are not on the back stack; fragment *transactions* are.

Comment: I got it. But I have the following scenario\n in which there are 3 fragments FragmentA1,FragmentA2,FragmentA3. I have added FragmentA1 and FragmentA2 to backstack but not FragmentA3. So, if i press back button from FragmentA3, then it is finishing FragmentA2 and it is overriding the FragmentA3 in FragmentA1. Please help me in sorting this issue

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585: Feel free to open a new StackOverflow answer where you explain your problem, to see if anyone can help.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, now raised as question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865438/android-fragment-back-button-overlays-other-fragment-and-keeps-active and Google Issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68160