# Android Fragment Back Button overlays other fragment and keeps active

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my App I have 3 fragments.

App Starts with [1], User can only navigate to [2] and then optionally to [3].

Since [3] is deep down, I want [3] to go back to [1] directly.

Currently I call [2] using addToBackStack(null). Since I do NOT call addToBackStack on [3] I assumed it will go back to [1].

What happens is, that [3] returns to [1], but now both fragments are displayed overlapping. Fragment [3] does not call onPause(). Calling fragment [2] again will display [2] on top of the others, not clearing the screen.

Navigating back and forth will crash the app. Sometimes on opening a new fragment, sometimes when hitting the back button. Always with "Fragment already added" error (which is extremely odd for the back button, but I check that also before switching fragments).

Any ideas what might cause this odd behavior? Using addToBackStack or [3] also eliminates the problem, but does not solve my requirement. I do call all super methods where appropriate.

Info: Code Sample for Download at http://beadsoft.de/android/FragmentTest.zip

Same behavior on 2.x, 4.2.2. Using ActionBarCompat.

Code for adding fragment:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(Fragment_xyz.FRAG_TAG);
    if (fragment == null)
        fragment = Fragment_xyz.newInstance(int data);
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, Fragment_xyz.FRAG_TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on how fragments work. See the following life cycle of the above app:

```
LifeCycle of the App
start
04-07 20:34:46.115: D/Fragment_1(15309): onCreateView Fragment_1
04-07 20:34:46.115: D/Fragment_1(15309): onResume Fragment_1
Click to open 2
04-07 20:34:49.148: D/Fragment_1(15309): onPause Fragment_1
04-07 20:34:49.148: D/Fragment_2(15309): onCreateView Fragment_2
04-07 20:34:49.148: D/Fragment_2(15309): onResume Fragment_2
Click to open 3
04-07 20:34:53.633: D/Fragment_2(15309): onPause Fragment_2
04-07 20:34:53.633: D/Fragment_3(15309): onCreateView Fragment_3
04-07 20:34:53.633: D/Fragment_3(15309): onResume Fragment_3
back Button. Since 3 is not on backstack, app returns to 1 (not pausing 3)
Here Frag 1 and 3 are running and displayed overlaying!
04-07 20:35:03.653: D/Fragment_1(15309): onCreateView Fragment_1
04-07 20:35:03.653: D/Fragment_1(15309): onResume Fragment_1
back Button on 1 - App exit
04-07 20:35:23.474: D/Fragment_1(15309): onPause Fragment_1
04-07 20:35:23.474: D/Fragment_3(15309): onPause Fragment_3
```

Issue now raised with Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68160

Having this and navigating back and forth will crash the app because the FragmentManager basically pauses and resumes the wrong fragments.

Answer (score 0):

why not adding every fragments to the backstack? Instead of:

```
MyNewFragment f=new MyNewFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, f).commit();
```

Try:

```
MyNewFragment f=new MyNewFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.container, f).commit();
```

Comment: How does the app then go directly from fragment 3 to 1, skipping 2 when the user hits the back button?